# Pinch to Zoom a UIImageView in CollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to add an IBAction to pinch and zoom an image to a custom cell class, but storyboard gives an error that actions cannot be targeted at repeating content. 
Here is the custom cell class:

```
class PhotoCell: UICollectionViewCell {

// Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var photoImgV: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var captionTV: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var captionBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var captionStackView: UIStackView!
@IBOutlet weak var likeCountLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var comntCountLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer!

// Actions
@IBAction func pinch(sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
        let currentScale = self.photoImgV.frame.size.width / self.photoImgV.bounds.size.width
        let newScale = currentScale*sender.scale
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: newScale, y: newScale)
        self.photoImgV.transform = transform
        sender.scale = 1
    }
}

@IBAction func showCaption(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        if self.captionStackView.arrangedSubviews[1].isHidden {
            self.captionStackView.arrangedSubviews[1].isHidden = false
        }else{
            self.captionStackView.arrangedSubviews[1].isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

It allowed me to connect an IBAction to a button to show/hide caption in the same cell, so why pinch isn't allowed? How would I pinch and zoom an image in a cell?

Comment: UICollectionViewCell?  You need to use the closure or whatever and let the view controller handle it.

Comment: thanks for your help, I solved it by creating the pinch gesture in awakeFromNib() method and attaching it to the imageView there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by deleting the pinch gesture from storyboard and creating it in the awakeFromNib() method:

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let pinch = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.pinch(sender:)))
     photoImgV.addGestureRecognizer(pinch)
}
```

everything else is the same.